# Receiving addresses via DHCP does not work

Tags: networking, dhcp, hyper-v

I have created in Hyper-V, 3 systems:

- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Windows 10 Enterprise
- Windows Server 2022

All of them are connected to a Hyper-V virtual Switch (Private)
In Windows Server.

I created the DHCP role and configured it.

Adapters in Windows 10 are configured to automatically receive IP (DHCP)

What is the problem?

Currently, all systems have ip addresses from the reserved range of `169.254.*.*`

The systems do not ping with each other either.

**UPD:**

The problem was that i didn't turn on network discover. However, the "Turn on network discovery" setting is reset when saving and instead you need to activate "Turn on file and printer sharing", although this is completely different. Is this undefined behavior?

Also, I did not activate the "scope" in the DHCP settings) It was not obvious to me, and in various manuals it was not.

Comment: Just to confirm, you added the DHCP role to the Windows Server 2022 guest and not the host, right?

Comment: Try a regular Internal or External Switch. I hook up Hyper-V systems routinely this way.

Comment: `169.254.*.*` is a special subnet suggesting that there isn't a DHCP server that is accessible. If your servers have that local link IP address then they are not being assigned an actual IP address.  This is true if the servers have an address between 169.254.0.1 and 169.254.255.254.  The servers not being able to ping each other is expected.  My suggestion is assign a static ip address since you have a virtual network switch configured.

Comment: I have assigned static addresses (192.168.10.20/24 and 192.168.10.30/24), but the hosts are still not pinged. They should ping if they are on the same network, right?

Comment: I also connected pfSense installed in Hyper-v to this private switch, and the DHCP server installed on pfSense distributed ip addresses. I don't understand why DHCP on Windows Server doesn't work either. I haven't created an AD yet. Maybe because of this?

Comment: Internal switch: isolates the virtual machines but allows network switching between the Hyper-V host and the virtual machines. Private Switch: Completely isolates the network from virtual machines.   Source:   https://rdr-it.com/en/hyper-v-the-different-virtual-switches/#:~:text=Internal%20switch%3A%20isolates%20the%20virtual,the%20network%20from%20virtual%20machines.   ...  I think you should try an internal switch.   Private is like Host Only.

Comment: But the internal switch has internet access, which I wanted to avoid. Apparently I will migrate to VirtualBox.

Comment: Isolated machines (Hyper-V, VMware (I use these) and Virtual Box)  are just that and do not work the way you wish.

Comment: @Rsmtq AFAIK internal switch itself does not imply Internet access (with the "default switch" being a special case for convenience). Whether the VM gets Internet access with normal / manually created private switch depends on whether IP forwarding (and corresponding source NAT) is enabled on the host.